# Compare field in derived template class

Tags: c++

I have two classes in library:

```
class A
{
    public:
    int x;
};

template <class T>
class B : public A
{
    public:
    T y;

};
```

And have method:

```
... Method(A &a, A &b);
```

How compare y from a and b if a, b always have same type

```
B <T>
```

, but type of T unknown?

Comment: "How compare y from a and b if a, b always have same type B" - but `a` and `b` have type `A`, but not `B`

Comment: how do you plan to access y using a and b in the method you described?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a function,

```
Method(A a, A b);
```

You have lost the `B` part of the objects due to object slicing.

If you want retain the `B` part of the objects, you have to use references or pointers.

```
Method(A const& a, A const& b);
```

or

```
Method(A const* a, A const* b);
```

In order for `Method` to work correctly, you have to provide a way for the objects to be treated as `B`. You can use that using a `virtual` function in `A`.

```
class A
{
    public:
    int x;
    virtual int compare(A const& rhs) const
    {
        return (this->x - rhs.x);
    }
};
```

and make sure to override the function in `B`.

```
template <class T>
class B : public A
{
    public:
    T y;
    virtual int compare(A const& rhs) const
    {
       // Use the base class first.
       int r = A::compare(rhs);

       // If the base class result is adequate, return.
       if ( r != 0 )
       {
          return r;
       }

       // Do a dynamic_cast of the rhs.
       B const* rhsPtr = dynamic_cast<B const*>(&rhs);

       // If the dynamic_cast didn't succeed, need
       // to figure out how to handle the case.
       if ( rhsPtr == nullptr )
       {
          // Add error handling code
       }

       return (this->y - rhsPtr->y);
    }
};
```

Then, in `Method`,

```
Method(A const& a, A const& b)
{
   int r = a.compare(b);
}
```

Comment: But if I can't change classes A and B?

Comment: @ZregerZ, if you can't change classes `A` and `B`, you have to include all the `dynamic_cast`-ing code in `Method`. That will be  almost impossible since `B` is a class template. You can't just `dynamic_cast` to `B`, you have to `dynamic_cast` to `B<T>`. How would `Method` know what `T` to use?

Comment: @ZregerZ, exactly. That doesn't sound like it's maintainable code.

Comment: @R Sahu, Method knowns only that a and b have field y of one type.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create a virtual function that will do the comparison.

Inside the body of the implementation in the derived class the type `T` is known and you'll have no problems.

```
struct Base {
  ...
  virtual bool same_y(const Base& other) const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base {
    T y;
    virtual bool same_y(const Base& other) const {
        return dynamic_cast< const Derived<T>& >(other).y == y;
    }
};
```

Comment: What to do if I can't change classes?

Answer (score 0):

You could define `Method` as a template method.

```
template<typename T>
bool Method(const A& a, const A& b)
{
    const B<T>& first = dynamic_cast<const B<T>&>(a);
    const B<T>& second = dynamic_cast<const B<T>&> (b);
    return first.y == second.y;
}
```

With this approach you don't have to know the type of `T` inside `Method`. But you have to specify `T` when you call it:

```
bool areEqual = Method<int>(a, b);
```

Maybe that is no problem in your case.

Be aware that whenever you assign a `B<T>` to a variable of type `A` you are loosing the information that is specific to `B<T>` (in this case the value of `y` is lost). That's why I changed the signature of `Method` in order to take references instead of values.

Comment: Here, you have slicing problem. And I would use `dynamic_cast` anyway.

Comment: And you may also avoid copies if `first` and `second` were const reference.